# regex to delete all dots in a line starting with specific word

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to change this:

```css
.my-class {
  @apply .p-4 .bg-red-500;
}
```

into this:

```css
.my-class {
  @apply p-4 bg-red-500;
}
```

I found this regex but it is not working:

```
(?<=@apply.*)\.
```

any ideas?

Comment: What programming language or regex flavor are you using?

Comment: it works in an environment where the lookbehind with an infinite quantifier is supported. See https://regex101.com/r/GGRqjq/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will work in .NET or Python PyPi `regex` module or JavaScript ECMAScript 2018+ compliant environments that support infinite-width lookbehind patterns.

If it is PCRE/Java/Ruby, you can use

```
((?:\G(?!^)|@apply)[^.\r\n]*)\.
```

And replace with `$1` backreference to Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UTENji/2). I assumed you want to find dots on the same line as `@apply`, so I added `\r` and `\n` to the negated character class, if it is not so, remove `\r` and `\n`.

*Details*:

- `((?:\G(?!^)|@apply)[^.\r\n]*)` - Group 1: either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or `@apply` and then zero or more chars other than a dot, CR and LF chars
- `\.` - a dot

Comment: Worked perfect in a php function, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to change all sass files in a directory like this:

```php
<?php
foreach(glob('./site/assets/stylesheets/' . sprintf("**/*.%s", 'sass')) as $file) {
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  $regex = '/((?:\G(?!^)|@apply)[^.\r\n]*)\./m';
  $subst = '$1';

  $result = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $contents);

  file_put_contents($file, $result);
  echo "written $file";
}
```